# Add node value near the node filed into my RadTreeView

Tags: c#, .net, telerik, nodes, radtreeview

I have `Winforms` application and `RadTreeView`, every node that added represent file on disk.
Please see this code:

```
private void add(string file)
{
    file = @"c:\file.pdf";
    RadTreeNode filename = radTreeView1.Nodes.Add(file);
    //filename.CheckType = CheckType.CheckBox;
    filename.Expanded = true;

    RadTreeNode dhcp = filename.Nodes.Add("File details: ");
    dhcp.Expanded = false;
    dhcp.CheckType = CheckType.CheckBox;
    RadTreeNode clientIdentifier = dhcp.Nodes.Add("Size: ");
    clientIdentifier.Nodes.Add("");
    RadTreeNode requestedIp = dhcp.Nodes.Add("Length:");
    requestedIp.Nodes.Add("");
}
```

And the result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYAcA.png

As you can see after each file property (for example size) i have the value which i can edit but all i want to achieve is that this property value will locate near the property field and only the value will be edit after `F2` click.
Currently my property value is in different node that the property field (size).
Is it possible to do that ?